# Bypassing CanCan::AccessDenied while running RSpec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, authorization, cancan

I'm trying to run a strong parameters test for my `Restaurant` model and am running into an error that's keeping from progressing in development . In its controller I have the CanCan method `load_and_authorize_resource` to permit only admins to create, update, and destroy these model instances:

```
class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource param_method:  :restaurant_params, find_by: :slug
  ...
end
```

When it comes to running tests though I get the error:

```
  1) RestaurantsController should permit POST #create to receive parameters :name
     Failure/Error: should permit(:name).
     CanCan::AccessDenied:
       You are not authorized to access this page.
```

Is there simple way to bypass this authorization? I've looked all throughout SO and there doesn't seem to be a clear answer.

**Test**

```
describe RestaurantsController do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, admin: true) }

  it { should permit(:name).for(:create) }
end
```

**NOTE:** I've taken a look at the [docs](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities#controller-testing) over on the CanCan and they say to create an instance of a user with its admin attribute set to true. Even with this I'm still a little confused on how to insert this user in my test.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I've concluded that the best way to bypass this has more to do with **logging in** my `User` factory via [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)) more than dealing with the CanCanCan gem itself.

Depending on your setup this may vary but for my user factory I have my `admin` attribute set to `true`.

**user.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name "John"
    last_name "Doe"
    email "john@example.com"
    password "password"
    admin true
  end
end
```

I then created a sub-directory inside my `spec` folder called `support` and followed the example in the Devise link provided to create the appropriate module method for logging in the user:

**spec/support/controller_macros.rb**

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    end
  end
end
```

Then in my `rails_helper` file I simply extended this module so that I could use the `login_admin` method. What the Devise example **DID NOT** mention was that you needed to `require` the `controller_macros` file in this helper. It may be understood by some but can be potentially overlooked if not careful:

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'support/controller_macros'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
    ....
    config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller

    config.extend ControllerMacros, type: :controller
end
```

Lastly in your controller tests just apply the `login_admin` method wherever need be:

**Restaurant Controller Tests**

```
describe RestaurantsController do
  login_admin

  it { should permit(:name).for(:create) }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I bypassed cancan's `load_and_authorize_resource` call with the following since i intend to test abilities separately.

```
before { allow_any_instance_of(CanCan::ControllerResource).to receive(:load_and_authorize_resource){ nil } }
```